# preventDefault is not a function error when trying to pass an image

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I'm using an image cropper to crop an image. I'm using the following library

https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor

I have implemented this correctly and i'm getting the cropped image using this function.

```
handleSave = () => {
  const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL();

  this.props.croppedImage(img);
};
```

Here i have passed the cropped image using props to another function as follows

```
this.props.croppedImage(img);
```

This is where i have implemented the cropper (2nd component)

```
<CropperTest croppedImage={this.getCroppedImg}/>
```

In the 2nd component i have used this function to access the cropped image and again pass that image to another function. This is where i get the issue.

```
getCroppedImg(img) {
    this.props.onImageImgPoll(img);
}
```

**onImageImgPoll function**

```
onImageImgPoll(event) {

event.preventDefault();
let array = this.state.filepoll.slice();
let unq_file = event.target.files[0];

if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {

  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    array.push(unq_file);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(unq_file);

  this.setState({
    image: event.target.result,
    filepoll: array,
    filestar: []
  });

}

};
```

When running this code i'm getting this error

```
event.preventDefault is not a function
```

What I've found out is the cropped image is in base64 format. Maybe that might be the issue. How can i solve this?

Comment: `img` is not an event, so therefore, has no event properties

Comment: You are not passing an event there. Also pass event along with image

Comment: @JaromandaX how should i pass the image ?

Comment: What event are you trying to prevent?

Comment: you are passing the image, I think you are confused about the issue

Comment: try doing this: this.getCroppedImg.bind(this) see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @Mike i have already done it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `this.onImageImgPoll= this.onImageImgPoll.bind(this);` in your component constructor